# How to handle "default" exceptions in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

Imagine this scenario:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int myParam)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something useful
        return RedirectToAction("NextAction");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
}
```

This ends up on a Yellow Screen Of Death rather than my Error controller. I can mask that of course, but I want a return here. So, I tried this instead:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int myParam)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something useful
            return RedirectToAction("NextAction");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
    }
}
```

But that won't compile, saying that not all paths return a value, even though any path through that code ought to end up with an ActionResult. Same if you put the return inside a `finally` command, complaining that "Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause".

Is there a better way to handle this, or am I doing to have to leave a dangling default return at the bottom of this controller action?

Comment: it's saying " not all paths return a value because not all paths return value what if (ModelState.IsValid) is false?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compile that , because of you forget this part

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int myParam)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something useful
            return RedirectToAction("NextAction");
        }
        else{
       return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
    }
}
```

If this is model state not valid there is no returing View.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is better way. You can create base controller for your controllers, and there you can override OnException method that will fire if any exception in your child classes action methods occurs. You can then render error page from there or do some custom common error handling. So you don't need to have that try catch.

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
    }
```

btw: If you are new to MVC i would strongly advice to use T4 template to generate "strongly typed" paths from your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing via different way.

**Catching Exceptions in Controllers**

In controller  we have method OnException.override that method and write your logic.

```
 <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="ErrorPage.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
```

**Catching Exception at global level** 
we have one method **Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)** where we can catch exception and show custom page with tag in system.webconfig file

Using **handle error attribute** also we can do this and specify different error page.
[HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(NullReferenceException), View="Error")]